# React app doesn't wait for api respones to call componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I had to basically use below react app for TV guide based on Canvas(no idea why its react app)

```
https://github.com/SatadruBhattacharjee/react-tv-epg
```

However, after I made changes to get data from API instead of dummy data, it calls `componentDidMount` even before the api response comes.

I have zero experiance in react, so can't figure out how to fix it.

My code is

```
constructor() {
 
        this.channels = null;
        this.init();
    }
    async init() {
        try {
            this.channels = await this.getChannelData();
           
            console.log("Data received:", this.channels);
        } catch (error) {
            // Handle error
            console.error("Error:", error);
        }
    }
    getChannelData() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            MockDataService.getChannelData(function(response) {
                if (response) {
                    resolve(response);
                } else {
                    reject("Error fetching data");
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

After api is called with `getChannelData` , react app calls componentDidMount and tries to render app even before api response comes.

As api call is asynchronous, I was expecting promise to fix it, however it doesn't matter in this case.

Anyone can see on github code of this app, although it simply sets dummy data there. I am just setting actual data inside `EPGData` class

Method which returns response from api :

```
 static getChannelData(callback) {
    let channels = new Array();
    MockDataService.getEpgChannelData(function(error, response) {
        if (error) {
            // Handle error
            console.error('Error in getChannelData:', error);
              callback();
        } else {
            // Handle response
            var dataSections = response;
            for(let i=0; i< dataSections.length; i++) {
                let epgChannel = new EPGChannel(dataSections[i].id, dataSections[i].title, dataSections[i].logo);
                epgChannel.events = MockDataService.createChannelEvents(dataSections[i].tiles);
                channels.push(epgChannel);
            }
            callback(channels);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Maybe add a `if(channels !== null) { return ...`

Comment: Norman Pleitez I don't understand how it will fix it.

Comment: What is `MockDataService.getChannelData` since it's not part of the repo?

Comment: James I have updated my question. It's simply a method which calls api to get data

Comment: James My code only adds api call. Because react app is quite fast and renders app before even api response comes, it breaks for me. Even using async wait or promises.

Comment: Initialize a state variable to track whether the data is loaded, so when your data is fetched, now you can update the state to indicate that the loading is complete.

Comment: Davi Amaral Thanks. I will see how to do that. New to react and been asked to do this when I have no knowledge of react for client demo.

Comment: tldr, don't plan on delaying the render. Instead, have the render capable of dealing with the fact that the data isn't available initially. It's not ideal to leave the user on the previous page or on a white page waiting on a fetch when you could instead control what is being displayed until the fetch is complete.

Comment: Kevin B Yes, once I get the first part working, I would try to add loading dots or similar on the screen before app can be rendered fully

Comment: What Davi said, it is kinda the same. You have to wait for the response to be ready, you can use an extra state as loader, but the thing is that you need to wait for the data to be ready to proceed with the return.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comments, I was able to resolve it using state.

```
constructor(dataReadyCallback) {
        this.dataReadyCallback = dataReadyCallback;
        this.channels = null;
        this.init();
    }

async init() {
        try {
            this.channels = await this.getChannelData();
            // Your code to execute after receiving data
            console.log("Data received:", this.channels);
            this.dataReadyCallback && this.dataReadyCallback();
             
        } catch (error) {
            // Handle error
            
            console.error("Error:", error);
        }
    }

    getChannelData() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            MockDataService.getChannelData(function(response) {
                if (response) {
                    resolve(response);
                } else {
                    reject("Error fetching data");
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

And then relevant changes in component to ensure it's rendered after data fetched callback

```
 onDataReady() {
        this.resetBoundaries();
        this.setState({ isDataLoaded: true });
    }
```